HUGE WRINKLED DRESS
Purchased a dress from SHEIN which came in the mail today in a small bag and it has huge wrinkles all over it. Tag says no dry cleaning or putting in a dryer. How do I get the wrinkles out of this dress. It is for a wedding in 2 weeks. Will NEVER buy clothing from SHEIN again.

There is a travel hack for "ironing" clothing when you do not have a dryer or iron available. Consider hanging the dress in the bathroom and running a very hot shower. The hot steam will be similar to spraying it with water, and it can get wrinkles out with the combination of "steam" + "gravity".
I've found that giving it a gentle shake to "settle" the wrinkles while doing that will be better then just leaving it to hang in a steamy warm room.

It is not as good as ironing, but it is another way to attempt to deal with wrinkles.

You do not need to clean it (the way you explain). You just need to iron it. Shirts for men have the same problem: out of the bag, they look new and terribly wrinkled.
You just need to iron it. it might be needed to spray some water on it, and let it rest for 10-20 min, before the actual ironing process.
NOTE: If you are afraid that the dress might become smaller after washing (some clothes do have this huge problem, I have myself a few new shirts already unwearable because of that), then do not spray a lot of water on it. If needed, spray again where it is needed.

There are several layers to this problem:

No dry cleaning, no dryer: This is put on the label because Shein clothign is notorious for it's low quality. Putting the dress though dry cleaning or a dryer would probably damage it or distort it beyond repair. Don't buy such cheap clothing, you only get what you pay for.
As other already stated, wrinkles are best removed with an iron. Slightly dampening the fabric increases the likelihood that the iron can actually remove the wrinkles.
If you don't have an iron or don't want to use one on the dress, soak it in cool water instead, then put the soaking wet dress (without wringing) on a sturdy hanger and let it air dry (best over the bathtub or anywhere the dripping water doesn't cause damage). The weight of the wet fabric alone is able to reduce most wrinkles. To help it along, gently pull the fabric straight while it's still wet.


I had never been on the Shein website before and had no idea of what was going on but should have known better with it being from the Chinese. I just wish they weren't able to advertise on FB, it is false advertising. My fault when there was no description on the dress. Good thing it was cheap so not out of much of a loss. Thank you!

@LindaHolthaus Honestly, all of the fast fashion labels have the same problem to a certain extend, but some of them - like shein - have perfected the "wear once, throw away" kind of fashion. When you see a dress for 10$ and one for 50$ that look kind of the same online, you might feel like the cheap dress is the better option, but if you could see and feel them in a store, you'd probably notice the difference in fabric quality. There's also the moral implication of labor that's so cheap it borders on slavery, stealing of designs and the over-consumption of natural resources by these labels.

There is a spray in the laundry soap aisle in most stores, I forget the brand but its called "Wrinkle Release" since you cant dry clean or put in dryer, most likely the fabric can not be ironed, all the other answers with just water will probably work, but take more time. Its just a could dollars just spray on any fabric and the wrinkles are gone, and it smells great!

You could try spraying water on the dress, stretching it and laying it out to dry. This way, you do not have to wash the dress and it takes less time to dry but easily removes the wrinkles.
